# Which version of apache hadoop is compiled with jdk7?

Tags: java, hadoop, installation

I want to install a version of hadoop that dosn't have yarn and works with jdk7?

Can i use hadoop 1.x.x with jdk7?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Java versions that have been tested with Hadoop here:
[Hadoop Java Versions](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopJavaVersions)

Comment: Thanks but i want to know that does hadoop 1.x.x work with jdk7?

Comment: No problem.  I thought the page had the relevant version #'s, but apparently not.  There were some issues with some of the Hadoop versions and 7; however, they should be fixed:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-8329